# Bulk Update Permissions in Orbeon Forms

Tags: orbeon

In order to activate drafts I need to set Permission (Create + Owner Update,View ,Delete) in all my forms definition ( hundreds) .

Is there a way (API) to do it in bulk mode? Otherwise all forms definition have to be modified manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways to do this programmatically:

- Using APIs

  - This assumes you have all the forms accessible from the Form Builder summary page, and are OK republishing them as-is.
  - Get the list of all the forms with the [search API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/search).
  - Retrieve the source of the form with the [CRUD API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/crud).
  - Make the changes to the form definition.
  - Publish the new version using the [publish API](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/other-apis/publish).
- Changing the form definitions at the database level

  - In this case you'll be working with SQL, and making changes to the form definitions in-place, in `orbeon_form_definition` table.

Comment: Thank you , I'll try with second approach since is a one time task

Comment: @user2299547 Sounds good; this is most likely what I would do as well. You'll let me know how it works out!

Comment: Thank you I worked!

I successfully  updated **orbeon_form_definition.form_metadata** column with oracle db   as persistence provider !

In my case my permissions are  
1.Create from everyone  
2. Read Update Delete from Owner 
I inserted  into metadata tag this node :
 `<permissions>
  <permission operations="read update delete">
   <owner/>
  </permission>
  <permission operations="create"/>
 </permissions>`
The only problem was that in order to use xml oracle operand as  INSERTCHILDXML and DELETEXML extra conversions from/to xml are needed. @avernet

Comment: Cool @RobertoDemozzi, I am glad this worked for you, and thank you for the update. ‑Alex